# Does the VC implementation of putenv() support a local variable as a parameter?

Tags: visual-c++, environment-variables

As far as I know the POSIX/Linux incarnation of putenv() does not create a copy of the string it is given as a parameter and thus is not save to be called with e.g. a local char array as its parameter.

What I would like to know is whether the Microsoft/VC implementation of putenv() also has this limitation.

As I see it the MSDN docs do not say so explicitly (as opposed to the POSIX docs returned e.g. by checking man putenv() on Linux).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The POSIX function `putenv` is deprecated in favour of `_putenv` and (at least in VS2012) won't compile. However, using `_putenv` and stepping into the debugger confirms that the passed string **is** copied. A section of relevant code for info (the passed string is called `name`):

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks! As a sidenote: How did you manage to step into _putenv() in a debug build? Mine simply refuses to do so. Is this related to me compiling my program with the /MDd flag set (i.e. does this only work for static CRT linkage)? Or did I miss something else here? I am using VS2008 by the way...

Comment: @Bjoern You're welcome - as long as you're not using Visual Studio Express, and you did a full install, you get most of the MFC/ATL/CRT source too.

Comment: Just to be complete: I just checked this and can confirm that the above is true for VS2008 as well.